# Show local notification when the app is opened in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, notifications, apple-push-notifications, flutter-local-notification

I'm using [`flutter_local_notifications`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package and it's showing notifications when the app is opened (foreground) in Android but not in the iOS. The [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/#handling-notifications-whilst-the-app-is-in-the-foreground) says:

> For iOS 10+, use the presentation options to control the behaviour for when a notification is triggered while the app is in the foreground. The default settings of the plugin will configure these such that a notification will be displayed when the app is in the foreground.

If I understood it right, I don't need to do anything on my own except (correct me if I'm wrong and this is what the question is all about). This is the code I'm using. (Works in both iOS and Android except the foreground part)

```dart
Future<void> showNotification() async {
  final notificationPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  const androidSettings = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  const iOSSettings = IOSInitializationSettings();
  final initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: androidSettings,
    iOS: iOSSettings,
  );
  await notificationPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onSelectNotification: (payload) async {},
  );

  const androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'foo_id',
    'Foo Name',
    'Foo description ',
    importance: Importance.max, 
    priority: Priority.defaultPriority,
    showWhen: false,
  );

  await notificationPlugin.show(
    1211, 
    'Notification title',
    'Notification body',
    NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails),
    payload: 'item x',
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in `AppDelegate.swift` try add the following :

- Swift:

```swift
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
              UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
            }
            func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
                     completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
                }
```

- Objective-C:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"10.0.0")) {
 (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center 
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification 
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Objective C, can you post the equivalent code for it?

Comment: I edit my answer , please check hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try in a day or so and will let you know.

Comment: Indeed adding the `if` statement fixed the issue for me for foreground notifications, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your project :

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
```

Comment: I already added that.

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to show local notification when app is in foreground. Alternatively you can use any **BannerView** package or design your custom BannerView to notify the user that will gives the feel of local notification in iOS. i did not tried with flutter but i am answering this question as an iOS developer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but did you try `flutter_local_notifications` plugin yourself because docs mentions that the notification can be displayed whilst the app is running in the foreground once it is properly configured. But I don't know how to configure it.